# Можно ли использовать имя для внешнего ключа?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть таблица стран. Поля:

```
id, country (UNIQUE).
```

Я использую **country** как внешний ключ. Это нормально, или принято использовать **id**?

Comment: Использовать можно. Но это ненормально, даже где-то bad practice. И строковые поля как поля связи медленнее числовых.

Comment: @Akina и это плохо даже для, например, стран или языков? Ведь в случае, когда есть имя, я могу просто вернуть данные. В противном случае, мне необходим JOIN.

Comment: В этом случае лучше думайте в сторону ENUM.

Comment: Думал. Но страны могут добавляться. Переделывать enum каждый раз может быть затратно. Руководствуюсь этим: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238579/mysql-enum-good-idea-for-iso-3166-1-country-codes

Comment: *страны могут добавляться* Не смешно даже. Список стран мира как бы не секрет, и меняется хорошо если раз в пять лет...

Comment: страны в enum запихивать так себе идея, по моему )

Comment: джойн или подзапрос к покрывающему индексу будет аццки быстр. Или речь о том, что вам лень писать этот джойн?

Comment: Там нечего писать. Опыта нет, вот и выясняю, какой подход лучше.